# CakePHP 3 Equivalent of Containable

Tags: cakephp-3.0

The Containable behavior was very useful in the preceding versions of CakePHP. Is there a replacement for Containable in version 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functionality "Containable" used to provide is now built-in into the Query objects.

Check the ORM migration guide for more details: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/orm-migration.html#recursive-and-containablebehavior-removed